# use extension function to change variable value

Tags: c#, function, return, this, extension-methods

Is there a way to use an extension method to change a variable to the return value?

I have a basic remap function

```
public static float Remap(this float value, float min1, float max1, float min2, float max2)
        => (value - min1) / (max1 - min1) * (max2 - min2) + min2;
```

`distance.Remap(0, 2, 120, 80);`

I want distance to have the value of the return without explicitly setting it like

`distance = distance.Remap(0, 2, 120, 80);`

Comment: Having a `ReMap` method available on all `float` objects will be confusing. Consider creating a wrapper structure eg. `struct Distance { public Distance(float value) => this.value = value; private float value; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ref` Should do this just fine.

By making the `this float value` a `ref` parameter,
You can alter the input by setting it as your return value.

```
 public static float Remap(this ref float value, float min1, float max1, float min2, float max2)
    => value = (value - min1) / (max1 - min1) * (max2 - min2) + min2;
```